Multiple update table from other table
I have the following simplified and shortened tables:
table_a:
 label  type  code
 -----  ----  ----
'----' 'ab'  '0123' <-- label will     be changed
'----' 'ab'  '8234' <-- label will     be changed
'----' 'ab'  '9176' <-- label will not be changed
'----' 'cd'  '4554' <-- label will     be changed
'----' 'cd'  '5122' <-- label will     be changed
'----' 'cd'  '7777' <-- label will not be changed

table_b:
 label  type  code
 -----  ----  ----
'KOTA'  'ab' '01'  <-- will     match
'KOTA'  'ab' '8'   <-- will     match
'KOTA'  'ab' '923' <-- will not match
'RRHW'  'cd' '4'   <-- will     match
'WWUP'  'cd' '512' <-- will     match

I update table a with this query:
UPDATE table_a AS a
  RIGHT JOIN table_b AS b
     ON a.type = b.type
    AND LEFT(a.code, LENGTH(b.code)) = b.code
    SET a.label = b.label;

It works but in the actual case in our database, this is very slow. There's no way I can change the database (adding an index or . . ). Is there a better (faster) way to update table a?

As an option you could try:  AND a.code LIKE CONCAT(b.code, '%'). I can't imagine it will be faster, but sometimes we get lucky. Are the codes always numeric? Is a.code always 4 digits?

Thanks. Yes code is always numeric with 4 characters.

If you have an index on code I think that may be able to take advantage of it.

Best may be a composite index on (type, code).

If something is slow, check the slow-query log, and you can also just add EXPLAIN to the start of the statement to get the perf info you need.

I don't see why this needs to be a right join and not an inner join. I don't know if the optimizer would pick this and convert to inner. A common cause of poor performance when joining char is collation and/or character set. If you can't change the db, you can try changing the collation for your purposes like this:
UPDATE table_a AS a
  INNER JOIN (
      select type, label,
      code collate collation_used_by_a.code
      from table_b
  ) AS b ON a.type = b.type
        AND LEFT(a.code, LENGTH(b.code)) = b.code
    SET a.label = b.label;


The sample in my question above is simplyfied therefore I tried your proposal on the actual challenge. Let me start by telling that the speed difference is amazing! Thanks!!!
26 seconds versus 0.2 seconds.
I sort of understand what the solution is about but I am on the edge of my knowledge here. So, don't know if the inner join or the collation makes the difference. I assume the latter.
Found out that the collation of table a (or the whole database?) is latin1_swedish_ci and table b had none. Table b is temporary in the actual case.
